# URL must be a string selenium - selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I am making a script to automate the buying process of clothes by making requests but I get the error saying that url must be a string without specific error in the title ill put the code below im just not sure which url it is referincing but any help with this would really be appreciated so thank you - arthur

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import random
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import requests
import webbrowser
from discord_webhooks import DiscordWebhooks
from datetime import datetime

class Profile:

  def __init__ (self, profileName, name, email, tel, address1, address2, zip, city, state, country, number, month, year, cvv):

      self.profileName = profileName
      self.name = name
      self.email = email
      self.tel = tel
      self.address1 = address1
      self.address2 = address2
      self.zip = zip
      self.city = city
      self.state = state
      self.country = country
      self.number = number
      self.month = month
      self.year = year
      self.cvv = cvv

class Item:

  def __init__ (self, product, color, size):

      self.product = product
      self.color = color
      self.size = size

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
profiles = [Profile]
webhook = DiscordWebhooks('empty for stack overflow')
headless = False

def lookingForItem():
  print("Monitoring")
  testItem = Item("Acrylic Visor 6-Panel", "Red", "N/A")
  monitor(testItem)
  productLink = findProduct(testItem)
  checkout(productLink, testItem)

def checkout(productLink, item):
  startTime = time.perf_counter()
  userProfile = Profile("test", "Test Name", "test@gmail.com", "1111111111", "1 Test St", "", "10001", "New York", "NY", "USA", "4111111111111111", "08", "2020", "111")
  driver.get(productLink)
  done = False
  delay = 0
  if item.size.lower() != 'n/a' and item.size.lower() != "any":
      if item.size.lower() == 'random':
          driver.execute_script("""var sizePicker = Math.floor(Math.random() * document.getElementById('s').length);
          document.getElementById('s').selectedIndex = sizePicker;""")
      else:
          driver.execute_script("""for (var i=0; i<document.getElementById('s').length; i++){{
                          if (document.getElementById('s').options[i].text == '{}'){{
                            document.getElementById('s').selectedIndex = i;
                          }}
                        }}""".format(item.size))
  while(not done):
      done = addToCart()
  done = False
  while(not done):
      done = goToCheckout()
  driver.execute_script("""document.getElementById('order_billing_name').value = '{}';
  document.getElementById('order_email').value = '{}';
  document.getElementById('order_tel').value = '{}';
  document.getElementById('bo').value = '{}';
  document.getElementById('oba3').value = '{}';
  document.getElementById('order_billing_zip').value = '{}';
  document.getElementById('order_billing_city').value = '{}';
  document.getElementById('order_billing_state').value = '{}';
  document.getElementById('order_billing_country').value = '{}';
  document.getElementById('rnsnckrn').value = '{}';
  document.getElementById('credit_card_month').value = '{}';
  document.getElementById('credit_card_year').value = '{}';
  document.getElementsByClassName('iCheck-helper')[1].click();""".format(
  userProfile.name, userProfile.email, userProfile.tel,
  userProfile.address1, userProfile.address2, userProfile.zip,
  userProfile.city, userProfile.state, userProfile.country,
  userProfile.number, userProfile.month, userProfile.year, userProfile.cvv))
  print("Delaying")
  time.sleep(delay/1000)
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="orcer"]').send_keys(userProfile.cvv)
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cart-cc"]/fieldset/p[2]/label/div/ins').click()
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pay"]/input').click()
  #webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LeWwRkUAAAAAOBsau7KpuC9AV-6J8mhw4AjC3Xz&co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc3VwcmVtZW5ld3lvcmsuY29tOjQ0Mw..&hl=en&v=oqtdXEs9TE9ZUAIhXNz5JBt_&size=invisible&cb=h0o95sjo44ya")
  print("Processing")
  endTime = time.perf_counter()
  finalTime = round((endTime - startTime), 3)
  sendWebhook(productLink, item, finalTime)

def sendWebhook(productLink, item, finalTime):
  webhook.set_content(color=0xCC3333,title='cheebBot1.0')
  webhook.add_field(name='Status', value='**Payment failed!**')
  webhook.add_field(name='Date/Time', value=str(datetime.now()))
  webhook.add_field(name='Item', value='**'+ item.product + '**')
  webhook.add_field(name='Item Link', value=productLink)
  webhook.add_field(name='Color', value=item.color)
  webhook.add_field(name='Size', value=item.size)
  webhook.add_field(name='Checkout Time', value=str(finalTime) + ' s')
  webhook.send()

def findProduct(item):
  container = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]').find_elements_by_class_name('inner-article')
  for article in container:
      if article.find_element_by_class_name("product-name").find_element_by_class_name("name-link").text == item.product and article.find_element_by_class_name("product-style").find_element_by_class_name("name-link").text == item.color:
          return(article.find_element_by_class_name("product-name").find_element_by_class_name("name-link").get_attribute("href"))

def monitor(item):
  try:
      driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(), "' + item.product + '")]')
  except NoSuchElementException:
      driver.refresh()
      monitor(item)
  return

def productListed(product):
  try:
      driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), " + product + ")]")
  except NoSuchElementException:
      time.sleep(.5)
      driver.refresh()
      productListed(product)
  return

def addToCart():
  try:
      driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="add-remove-buttons"]/input').click()
  except ElementNotInteractableException:
      time.sleep(.01)
      #driver.refresh()
      return False
  print("Adding to cart")
  return True

def goToCheckout():
  try:
      driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cart"]/a[2]').click()
  except ElementNotInteractableException:
      time.sleep(.01)
      return False
  print("Checking out")
  return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
  if headless:
      driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)
  else:
      driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver.get("https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/shirts/ziq2otwjc/c9qzbgrlm")
  lookingForItem()

#class euProfile: 
#   def __init__(self, name, age):
```

Answer (score 0):

It maybe in this code that have error:

```
def findProduct(item):
  container = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]').find_elements_by_class_name('inner-article')
  for article in container:
      if article.find_element_by_class_name("product-name").find_element_by_class_name("name-link").text == item.product and article.find_element_by_class_name("product-style").find_element_by_class_name("name-link").text == item.color:
          return(article.find_element_by_class_name("product-name").find_element_by_class_name("name-link").get_attribute("href"))
```

the code does not have a fallback when it did not satisfy the condition in for loop

Comment: im not sure if thats the case i can add one but the error given is here -> 

https://imgur.com/gallery/w3yLpSg

Comment: The error is pointing to this line:

driver.get(productLink)

and tracing into the code:

productLink = findProduct(testItem)
checkout(productLink, testItem)

Which leads me to this code again:

def findProduct(item):

now, please print the output from:

productLink = findProduct(testItem)

Comment: sorry please may you explain more what you mean? 

just on a guess on the driver.get(productLink) line i replaced it with     

driver.get(productLink = findProduct(testItem))

and this results with it saying name testItem is not defined

Comment: can you print the result of findProduct(testItem)?

Comment: how would i go about printing this im sorry?

Comment: `productLink = findProduct(testItem)`
`print(productLink)`

Comment: the result is here https://imgur.com/gallery/SAwvEPq

Comment: revert to previous changes in line 52 and 53 add this print(productLink)

Comment: i havent changed anything on line 52 or 53?

Comment: my apologies but we cannot move forward unless you understand your own code.

Comment: I modified you code a little bit to point out where the issue is. You should be seeing it one you run the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import random
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import requests
import webbrowser
from discord_webhooks import DiscordWebhooks
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver


class Profile:

    def __init__(self, profileName, name, email, tel, address1, address2, zip, city, state, country, number, month, year, cvv):
        self.profileName = profileName
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.tel = tel
        self.address1 = address1
        self.address2 = address2
        self.zip = zip
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.country = country
        self.number = number
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        self.cvv = cvv


class Item:

    def __init__(self, product, color, size):
        self.product = product
        self.color = color
        self.size = size


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, headless):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        profiles = [Profile]
        self.webhook = DiscordWebhooks('empty for stack overflow')

        if headless:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)
        else:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

        self.driver.get("https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/shirts/ziq2otwjc/c9qzbgrlm")


    def lookingForItem(self):
        print("Monitoring")
        testItem = Item("Acrylic Visor 6-Panel", "Red", "N/A")
        self.monitor(testItem)
        productLink = self.findProduct(testItem)
        print(productLink)
        self.checkout(productLink, testItem)


    def checkout(self, productLink, item):
        startTime = time.perf_counter()
        userProfile = Profile("test", "Test Name", "test@gmail.com", "1111111111", "1 Test St", "", "10001", "New York", "NY", "USA", "4111111111111111", "08",
                              "2020", "111")
        self.driver.get(productLink)
        done = False
        delay = 0
        if item.size.lower() != 'n/a' and item.size.lower() != "any":
            if item.size.lower() == 'random':
                self.driver.execute_script("""var sizePicker = Math.floor(Math.random() * document.getElementById('s').length);
              document.getElementById('s').selectedIndex = sizePicker;""")
            else:
                self.driver.execute_script("""for (var i=0; i<document.getElementById('s').length; i++){{
                              if (document.getElementById('s').options[i].text == '{}'){{
                                document.getElementById('s').selectedIndex = i;
                              }}
                            }}""".format(item.size))
        while (not done):
            done = self.addToCart()
        done = False
        while (not done):
            done = self.goToCheckout()
        self.driver.execute_script("""document.getElementById('order_billing_name').value = '{}';
          document.getElementById('order_email').value = '{}';
          document.getElementById('order_tel').value = '{}';
          document.getElementById('bo').value = '{}';
          document.getElementById('oba3').value = '{}';
          document.getElementById('order_billing_zip').value = '{}';
          document.getElementById('order_billing_city').value = '{}';
          document.getElementById('order_billing_state').value = '{}';
          document.getElementById('order_billing_country').value = '{}';
          document.getElementById('rnsnckrn').value = '{}';
          document.getElementById('credit_card_month').value = '{}';
          document.getElementById('credit_card_year').value = '{}';
          document.getElementsByClassName('iCheck-helper')[1].click();""".format(
            userProfile.name, userProfile.email, userProfile.tel,
            userProfile.address1, userProfile.address2, userProfile.zip,
            userProfile.city, userProfile.state, userProfile.country,
            userProfile.number, userProfile.month, userProfile.year, userProfile.cvv))
        print("Delaying")
        time.sleep(delay / 1000)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="orcer"]').send_keys(userProfile.cvv)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cart-cc"]/fieldset/p[2]/label/div/ins').click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pay"]/input').click()
        # webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LeWwRkUAAAAAOBsau7KpuC9AV-6J8mhw4AjC3Xz&co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc3VwcmVtZW5ld3lvcmsuY29tOjQ0Mw..&hl=en&v=oqtdXEs9TE9ZUAIhXNz5JBt_&size=invisible&cb=h0o95sjo44ya")
        print("Processing")
        endTime = time.perf_counter()
        finalTime = round((endTime - startTime), 3)
        self.sendWebhook(productLink, item, finalTime)


    def sendWebhook(self,productLink, item, finalTime):
        self.webhook.set_content(color=0xCC3333, title='cheebBot1.0')
        self.webhook.add_field(name='Status', value='**Payment failed!**')
        self.webhook.add_field(name='Date/Time', value=str(datetime.now()))
        self.webhook.add_field(name='Item', value='**' + item.product + '**')
        self.webhook.add_field(name='Item Link', value=productLink)
        self.webhook.add_field(name='Color', value=item.color)
        self.webhook.add_field(name='Size', value=item.size)
        self.webhook.add_field(name='Checkout Time', value=str(finalTime) + ' s')
        self.webhook.send()


    def findProduct(self, item):
        container = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]').find_elements_by_class_name('inner-article')
        for article in container:
            if article.find_element_by_class_name("product-name").find_element_by_class_name(
                    "name-link").text == item.product and article.find_element_by_class_name("product-style").find_element_by_class_name(
                    "name-link").text == item.color:
                return (article.find_element_by_class_name("product-name").find_element_by_class_name("name-link").get_attribute("href"))

        print("THERE IS NOT ELEMENT FOUND FOR THE HREF YOU ARE LOOKING FOR SO THIS WILL RETURN NONE")


    def monitor(self, item):
        try:
            self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(), "' + item.product + '")]')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            self.driver.refresh()
            self.monitor(item)
        return
```